# Definition of asymptotic flatness

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

This question is about an idea in general relativity, but its underlying realm is basically geometric. Let me begin with a snapshot of *Geometric Relativity* by Dan A. Lee:

[image]

I'd like to ask two questions. The first one is, why does Lee talk about the Euclidean background metric? Are we endowing $M$ with ***another*** metric? I mean, in the beginning of the definition, we are given a manifold $M$ ***already*** equipped with a Riemannian metric $g$. Can we impose ***another*** metric, possibly different from $g$, on $M$? Do geometers  really equip one ***single*** manifold with, if necessary, a couple of (distinct) metrics?

Let me ask one more question, please. In the inequality circled in red, I have no idea about those absolute values. What exactly is meant by $|x|$? That $x$ seems to be an arbitrary point in $M$, but how can we take its absolute value? Are we working in some coordinate chart, or something?

Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each end $M_k$, one has a particular chart
$\Phi_k \colon M_k \to \Bbb R^n \setminus \bar B_1(0)$, which is by definition a diffeomorphism.

On the LHS, you have the Riemannian metric $g$, and on the RHS, you have the euclidean metric $g_{eucl}$. One can pullback the euclidean metric on the LHS thanks to the diffeomorphism and define
$b_k = (\Phi_k)^*g_{eucl}$.
This is another Riemannian metric on the LHS.
One can show that the definition of $M_k$ to be asymptotically flat is equivalent to
$$
|{b_k}-g|_{b_k} = \mathcal{O}(|x|_{b_k}^{-q}).
$$
In other words, when you compare $b_k$ and $g$, where the measure is taken with reference to $b_k$, the error $e_k=b_k-g$ is small. In that case, $|x|_{b_k}$ is a short notation for $d(\Phi_k(x),0)$ is $\Bbb R^n$. Note that this asymptotic behaviour says that the geometry at infinity of $M_k$ is really close to be that of the euclidean space.

The reason we are comparing things on $M_k$ with respect to $b_k$ and not with respect to $g$ is for convinience: since this metric is euclidean, gradients, divergence *etc.* are easy to compute, and they are useful tool to define asymptotic geometric invariants.

Comment: I really appreciate your kindly help, but how could you figure out so many things from $$g_{ij}(x)=\delta_{ij}+O_2(|x|^{-q})?$$ Was it because the author had mentioned "in that coordinate chart"?

Comment: That's because $g_{ij}(x)$ is the coordinate expression in the chart $\Phi_k$ of the metric $g$ and $\delta_{ij}$ is that of the euclidean metrics! This definition appears to be highly dependant from the choice of the chart $\Phi_k$. Furtunately (surprisingly?), one can show that it is independant from that choice, so that it has real geometric meaning.

Anyway, you are right, all these things are hidden behind the simple mention "in that coordinate chart"

Comment: Pardon me for asking one more question. The notation $|{b_k}-g|_{b_k}$ is abstract for me. What did you possibly mean by taking the measure w.r.t. $b_k$? Thank you.

Comment: It's the norm on tensors induced by the metric $b_k$: for $x\in M$, $|T_x| = \sup_{X,Y\in T_xM, |X|=|Y|=1} |T_x(X,Y)|$.